# The type java.util.stream.BaseStream cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

This is a code, I wrote for functional programming to check the username I will get from url with the username present in the database.

```
package com.springboot.myfirstwebapp.todo;

import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.function.Predicate;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import jakarta.validation.Valid;

@Service
public class TodoService {

    private static List<Todo> todos = new ArrayList<>();
    
    private static int todosCount = 0;
    
    static {
        todos.add(new Todo(++todosCount, "OCS pending", LocalDate.now().plusYears(1), false));
        todos.add(new Todo(++todosCount, "JXP pro", LocalDate.now().plusYears(2), false));
        todos.add(new Todo(++todosCount, "Module maintenance", LocalDate.now().plusYears(3), false));
    }
    
    public List<Todo> findByUsername(String username)
    {
        Predicate<? super Todo> predicate = 
                todo -> todo.getUsername().equalsIgnoreCase(username);
        return todos.stream().filter(predicate).toList();
    }
```

This code was working fine but all of sudden it started showing an error at

```
return todos.stream().filter(predicate).toList();
```

saying, "The type java.util.stream.BaseStream cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files".

I did RnD with the help of Youtube and didn't find any optimal solution for it. I also searched for this error in Stackover Flow but didn't get the answer.

Comment: In future it helps if you provide a complete example - your code is missing the Todo class. In any case the code shown works fine, so whatever is causing your issue is not related to this code. It sounds like a runtime issue - it can't find BaseStream. Since this class is part of the core Java runtime library, this suggests something odd is happening with either your classpath or your JRE. If you run Java with the -verbose:class flag it will display more info about the class-loading, which might help diagnose the problem.

Comment: Thank you, so much for the help. I tried using jdk version-8 and the error got resolved but I tried switching back to jdk-17 and got the same mistake again. But, it was working perfectly fine till yesterday.

Comment: Do you mean it fails in jdk7 (that is jdk1.7) or it fails in jdk17? It sounds like you have used javac from jdk8 or higher and java runtime from before jdk8.

Comment: Please provide more information, such as operation system, exact JRE/JDK implementation (at compile-time and run-time), versions of dependencies, how you're compiling the project, how you're running the project, and so on. If you could reproduce this problem with a [mre], that would be ideal.

Comment: The operating system I am using is Windows 10 and I am using jdk version - 17.0.6, it is my workspace default JRE. The error is not shown while I am working on the 1.8 version, but the error shows up as soon as I switch from 1.8 to 17.0.6.

Comment: My problem got resolved.
I am using Eclipse IDE.
I deleted the JDK version 17 from my IDE and then, I went to my particular project properties - Java Build Path - libraries and again added the JavaSE-17 and  I chose the Workspace default JRE (jdk-17.0.6) and now it's running fine.